# How to eliminate values in a DOB result in such a way that each part of it doesn't contain more than the required number of digits?

Tags: python, pandas, string, logic

The DOB contains three parts, for example as shown below:

```
11/012/1992
```

The desired DOB output for the above example should be as follows:

```
11/12/1992
```

So, basically the code should eliminate the values in such a way that:

1. If the first part till the '/' contains more than 2 digits, the first one has to be eliminated.
2. If the second part till the '/' contains more than 2 digits, the first digit has to be eliminated.
3. If the third part till the '/' contains more than 4 digits, the first digit has to be eliminated.

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
def dob_postprocessing(in_str):
    if len(in_str) > 10:
        if in_str[2] != '/':
            in_str[0].replace(in_str[0], '', 1)
            
        if in_str[5] != '/':
            in_str[3].replace(in_str[3], '', 1)
            
        if len(in_str[6:]) > 4:
            in_str[6].replace(in_str[6], '', 1)
            
        else:
            return in_str
```

I am not getting the desired output. Can anyone please help me with this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.replace` to remove the unwanted parts:

```
# option 1, just remove the extra digits
df['DOB2'] = df['DOB'].str.replace(r'^.*?(\d{1,2}/).*?(\d{1,2}/).*?(\d{4})$', r'\1\2\3')

# option 2, also pad the missing digits
df['DOB3'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'].str.replace(r'^.*?(\d{1,2}/).*?(\d{1,2}/).*?(\d{4})$', r'\1\2\3'))
                .dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
             )
```

output:

```
             DOB        DOB2        DOB3
0    11/012/1992  11/12/1992  11/12/1992
1  011/012/01992  11/12/1992  11/12/1992
2      11/2/1992   11/2/1992  11/02/1992
```